# Unable import "cuxfilter" package in Kaggle Notebook environment

Tags: python, gpu, kaggle, rapids

I am working with a > 5GB CSV file for competition in Kaggle. I am using cudf and cuml for data preprocessing and machine learning. but for visualization, my plan was to use GPU accelerated visualization using Plotly. Since Kaggle docker doesn't include Rapids yet, I am using the following Dataset to install it.
https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/rapids

But i am unable to import "cuxfilter" package in the Kaggle notebook even after installing rapids using the above dataset.

```
import cuxfilter
```

is giving ModuleNotFoundError

Is there any way to install this package in Kaggle?

I have also tried to install the package using conda but it was unsuccessful. The command used was the following

```
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults cuxfilter=0.15 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.0
```

Please also find my post in kaggle discussion forum form more details
https://www.kaggle.com/cdeotte/rapids/discussion/190432#1046557

Comment: Can you please add the conda command that you used and the error?

Comment: added the command. The conda command was running indefinitely

Answer (score 2):

RAPIDS 0.15 release does not support CUDA10.0.
Please update your CUDA package or use RAPIDS 0.14 release

Command to install cuxfilter 0.14 using conda :

```
conda install -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge -c defaults cuxfilter=0.14 python=3.7 cudatoolkit=10.0
```